# How to define $U_q \mathfrak{g}$ without generators and relations?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, qa.quantum-algebra, hopf-algebras, quantum-groups

I'm trying to learn something about quantum groups. The related definitions tend to consist of formulas which are not extremely intuitive, on the first glance. So I wonder how the amount of formulas in the definitions may be reduced.

Let $\mathfrak g$ be a complex simple Lie algebra.

> **Question 1.** Can we define the ‘Jimbo–Lusztig’ quantum group $U_q\mathfrak{g}$ as a Hopf algebra over $\mathbb C(q)$ (where $q$ is a formal variable) without writing out its generators and relations?

This is related to [quantum groups... not via presentations](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/105221/quantum-groups-not-via-presentations) and [Can one define quantized universal enveloping algebras in a basis-free way?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/275841/can-one-define-quantized-universal-enveloping-algebras-in-a-basis-free-way), but I think my question is more basic, since I don't mind choosing anything about $\mathfrak{g}$ you would suggest (a Cartan subalgebra, a polarization of the root system, even a whole Cartan–Chevalley basis if you need it). I just don't want to write out the relations defining $U_q$, nor $U_\hbar$.

For $U_\hbar$ instead of $U_q$, one possible answer is given by the following theorem of Drinfeld, which describes a universal property that $U_\hbar\mathfrak{g}$ enjoys. (Its proof can be found in *Sternberg, Shnider, [Quantum groups, from coalgebras to Drinfeld algebras, a guided tour](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1287162),* theorem 11.4.1.)

> Recall that there is a natural bijection { real forms of $\mathfrak g$ } / isomorphism $\longleftrightarrow$ { involutive Lie algebra automorphisms of $\mathfrak g$ } / (conjugation by inner automorphisms of $\mathfrak g$). An involution which corresponds to the split real form of $\mathfrak g$ under this bijection is called a *Chevalley involution* (or a Cartan involution). If $H_\alpha, X_\alpha$ is a [Chevalley basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chevalley_basis) of $\mathfrak g$, then the linear map $H_\alpha\mapsto-H_\alpha$, $X_\alpha\mapsto -X_{-\alpha}$ is a Chevalley involution.
>
> Let us fix a Chevalley involution $\theta$ of $\mathfrak g$ and a Cartan subalgebra $\mathfrak h\subset\mathfrak g$ such that $\theta\bigr|_{\mathfrak h}=-\mathrm{id}_{\mathfrak{h}}$.
>
> Let $G$ be a topological Hopf algebra over the topological ring $\mathbb C[[\hbar]]$ (the topology on $\mathbb C[[\hbar]]$ being the $\hbar$-adic one). Let
>
> 1. $p:G/\hbar\to U\mathfrak g$ be an isomorphism of complex Hopf algebras,
> 2. $H\subset G$ a closed cocommutative Hopf subalgebra (over $\mathbb C[[\hbar]]$),
> 3. $\Theta$ an involutive automorphism of $G$ as a topological $\mathbb C[[\hbar]]$-module
>
> such that
>
> 1. $G$ is free as a topological $\mathbb C[[\hbar]]$-module,
> 2. the inclusion $H/\hbar\to G/\hbar$ corresponds via $p$ to the inclusion $U(\mathfrak{h})\hookrightarrow U(\mathfrak{g})$,
> 3. $\Theta$ is a homomorphism of algebras and an anti-homomorphism of coalgebras, $\Theta(H)=H$, and the automorphism of $G/\hbar$ induced by $\Theta$ corresponds via $p$ to $U(\theta):U(\mathfrak{g})\to U(\mathfrak{g})$.
>
> Then $G$ ‘is’ $U_\hbar\mathfrak{g}$. More precisely, $G$ together with the additional structure $(p,H,\Theta)$ is determined up to a unique isomorphism by the conditions stated above.

When $U_\hbar\mathfrak{g}$ is defined ‘in the usual way’ as a $\mathbb C[[\hbar]]$-algebra generated by $e_i,f_i,h_i$, then $U_q\mathfrak{g}$ is the $\mathbb C(q)$-subalgebra of $U_\hbar\mathfrak g\otimes_{\mathbb C[[\hbar]]}\mathbb C((\hbar))$ generated by $e_i$, $f_i$ and $e^{\hbar d_ih_i}$, where $q\mapsto e^\hbar$ and the $d_i$ are positive integers such that $\operatorname{min}d_i=1$ and the matrix $\mathrm{diag}(d_1,d_2\dotsc)C$ is symmetric, $C$ being the Cartan matrix. (The $d_i$ are uniquely determined by this condition, you can look them up, for example, in chapter V of *Ram's [Quantum Groups: A survey of definitions, motivations and results](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1690844)*.) However, this is still not a definition avoiding relations: even if I choose the generators $e_i,f_i,h_i$ of $\mathfrak{g}$ (which is something I am ready to do), I will have to lift them to $U_\hbar\mathfrak{g}$ in order to specify this subalgebra; I don't know how to describe the needed liftings without writing out the relations for $U_\hbar$, which is as bad as writing the relations for $U_q$.

The approach by Reshetikhin–Takhtadzhyan–Faddeev ([Quantization of Lie groups and Lie algebras](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=aa&paperid=7&option_lang=eng)  (see the end of the notes [An introduction to Tannaka duality and quantum groups](http://web.science.mq.edu.au/%7Estreet/CT90Como.pdf) by Joyal and Street for an English exposition) is interesting, but it gets too complicated for groups of $EFG$ types. (One has to specify the $R$-operator. The formula for $A_n$ is simple, it also helps to deal with the $BCD$ cases; but the formulas for $G_2$ look incomprehensible ([Sasaki - A Class of FRT Quantum Groups and $\operatorname{Fun}_q(G_2)$ as a Special Case](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9311149).)

---

> **Question 2.** Suppose $A$ is a Hopf algebra over $\mathbb C[q,q^{-1}]$ such that $A/(q-1)$ is isomorphic to $U\mathfrak g$ as a complex Hopf algebra. Is there a classification of such $A$ (‘integral forms’), or at least of Hopf algebras over $\mathbb C(q)$ which can be obtained as $A\otimes_{\mathbb C[q,q^{-1}]}\mathbb C(q)$ (‘rational forms’), perhaps with some additional structure?

If there were, we could use it to define $U_q\mathfrak g$. Note that $U_q\mathfrak g$ is not the unique rational form which can be obtained as $A\otimes_{\mathbb C[q,q^{-1}]}\mathbb C(q)$ from some integral form $A$ such that the $\hbar$-adic completion of $A\otimes_{\mathbb C[q,q^{-1}]}\mathbb C[[\hbar]]$ is isomorphic to the usual $U_\hbar\mathfrak g$. There are at least as many such rational forms as there are complex Lie groups with Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$: cf. *Chari, Pressley, [A guide to quantum groups](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1358358),* chapter 9.

Comment: There is a way through Tannaka reconstruction here [Quantum group as (relative) Drinfeld double?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/20683/quantum-group-as-relative-drinfeld-double).